# What is the algorithm behind multisignature address and redeem script?

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature

I know you can create a multisignature address with the command:

```
bitcoind createmultisig 2 ["pubkey1", "pubkey2", "pubkey3"]
```

As described here: https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071

This command returns the address (starting with character '3') and the redeem script.

My question: how to create multi-signature address and redeem script without using bitcoind? What algorithm is used?

Could you point me to some sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stole most of the answer from Andreas' book :-)

The bitcoin developer docs provide this [link here](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#pay-to-script-hash-p2sh), which goes over P2SH to multisig. The idea is to create a so called redeem script, which is a ripemd160(sha256(sigscript)).

Example from the book:

```
Redeem Script:    2 PubKey1 PubKey2 PubKey3 PubKey4 PubKey5 5 CHECKMULTISIG
Locking Script:   HASH160 <20-byte hash of redeem script> EQUAL
Unlocking Script: Sig1 Sig2 <redeem script>
```

see Andreas' book "Masterig Bitcoin, 2nd edition", page 152ff or in the GitHub version [here](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch07.asciidoc#with_p2sh).
The real book at http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/index.html

> how to create multi-signature address and redeem script without using
>   bitcoind? What algorithm is used?

you can use any hashing tools or libraries, Andreas shows with the "bx" library, openssl would do as well.